# How can I move DOM element of same classes recursively (jquery)

Tags: jquery

How can I move DOM element of same classes recursively?? for example, I have this code in DOM

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="mask">
        Content 1
    </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="mask">
        Content 2
    </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="mask">
        Content 3
    </div>
   <div class="thumbnail">
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to move divs of mask classes inside the divs of thumbnail classes so that code becomes like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="mask">
          Content 1
      </div>
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="mask">
         Content 2
      </div>
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="mask">
          Content 3
      </div>
      some content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to do this with jquery:

```
$('.mask').prependTo('.thumbnail');
```

but no success. I am getting "Content 1" copied in all thumbnail

somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

That will move all `.mask`s into all `.thumbnail`s. Instead, use `.each` to treat each element individually:

```
$(".mask").each() {
  $(this).next(".thumbnail").prepend(this);
});
```

Comment: what if .thumbnail is not just next element i.e what if there are few more elements between .mask and .thumbnail??

Comment: @Sakib Mohd: If it's a siblings with unknown position, try `.siblings(".thumbnail")`.

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple. Try this:

```
$(".mask").siblings(".thumbnail").prepend($(".mask"));
```

Works even if there are few more elements between .mask and .thumbnail!

**UPDATE:**

In case, you wanna do it for all the elements:

```
$(".mask").each(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".thumbnail").prepend(this);
});
```